# How to create a dynamic view that reads from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a server with sister databases. I currently have the following view that gets data from these databases

```
SELECT UnId FROM [DatabaseOne].[dbo].Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT UnId FROM [DatabaseTwo].[dbo].Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT UnId FROM [DatabaseThree].[dbo].Customers
```

However I often need to add or remove databases, so a static view doesn't seem like the best solution. I already have a table that contains all of the sister databases, as showcased below.

#### DATDB

```
UnId | DSTABLE
1    | DatabaseOne
2    | DatabaseTwo
3    | DatabaseThree
```

How can I create a dynamic view that reads this table?

Comment: You don't. A view cannot have dynamic sql and what you are talking about requires dynamic sql.

Comment: Create a stored procedure that will create the `create or replace` syntax of the view, based on looping through the records in datdb. Then the stored procedure should execute the dynamic sql you just generated, and voila, you have your dynamic view. Set the stored procedure to run as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sean clearly states, a view cannot be dynamic.

Something else you can do, besides Sam's comment, is put a TRIGGER on your `DATDB` table, AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that builds and executes a ALTER VIEW statement to change the view to select from the latest values in the `DATDB` table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider stored procedure that read DATADB table and create SELECT syntax for example and run it as dynamic SQL

```
declare @SQL varchar(1000)
declare @table as table (Unid int, DSTABLE varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table
select 1 as Unid, 'DatabaseOne' as DSTABLE union
select 2 as Unid, 'DatabaseTwo' as DSTABLE union
select 3 as Unid, 'DatabaseThree' as DSTABLE 



 SELECT @SQL = (STUFF((
        SELECT ' ' + ' SELECT Unid FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DSTABLE) + '.[dbo].[Customers] UNION ALL'
        FROM @table
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) -- Multiple rows to one row

SELECT @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 0, LEN(@SQL)-9) -- remove last UNION ALL
--exec (@SQL)
--print @SQL
```

Output

```
SELECT Unid FROM [DatabaseOne].[dbo].[Customers] UNION ALL  
SELECT Unid FROM [DatabaseTwo].[dbo].[Customers] UNION ALL  
SELECT Unid FROM [DatabaseThree].[dbo].[Customers]
```